# How to start Chrome (both normal & incognito modes) and open URL in remote PC (node) using Selenium Grid in Java?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-grid

I am trying Selenium Grid in Java and just want to start Chrome in both

- normal mode and
- incognito mode

in remote PC (node) and open google.com

I have setup the hub - node connection. 
I tried this code, but it seems to be wrong.

1. Any guidance how to do that?
2. How to use `capability.setCapability()`?  I found some [example](https://seleniumonlinetrainingexpert.wordpress.com/tag/setcapability/) to start IE and just replaced the word *InternetExplorer* with *Chrome* ... Doesn't work.

Thanks.

Not working code:

```js
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" , "C:/Users/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver;
       
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setCapability(ChromeDriver.BINARY, new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chrome.exe").getAbsolutePath());

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.0.106:1234/wd/hub"), capability);
driver.get("http://google.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Capabilities: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

2 - The "Icognito Mode" is a capability of the Chrome Browser - and it is set like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("-incognito");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

// For local usage
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

// For HUB usage
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("hub url here"), capabilities);
```

3 - You need to use backslashes for the system property pointing to your driver executable, also you need to escape those with additional backslahes if you are using JAVA:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\pathto\\my\\chromedriver.exe");
```

4 - For HUB usage, each node needs the chromedriver. Just put it in the same folder as your selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar and start the node like this:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="./chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json
```

Of course you need a nodeConfig that allows Chrome Browsers. Here is an example:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Normal mode:**

WebDriver driver;
driver=new ChromeDriver();

**incognito mode:**

   WebDriver driver;

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("-incognito");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```