# Using selenium without ChromeDriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So far I have used selenium only for testing purposes, but it is really nice and I would like to create a script that launch webpages but using the regular chrome with all my credentials etc.

When using selenium it used by default the ChromeDriver.

Any way to bypass it ? Or should I not ?

Comment: What do you mean `bypass`? If you don't have driver, how could you automatic control the browser? Even if you use Selenium Grid, it already has drivers for each kind of supported browsers.

Comment: When I launch the script it does not used my regular chrome but the chrome from the driver

Comment: Oh, that's [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome), which is a headless environment for testing.

Comment: The Chrome Driver is only used to control your browser, not including a portable version of Chrome (so are other drivers). And drivers are automatically start browser in headless mode. In case you want to start in other modes, try this out: [How to start Chrome (both normal & incognito modes) and open URL in remote PC (node) using Selenium Grid in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950530/how-to-start-chrome-both-normal-incognito-modes-and-open-url-in-remote-pc-n)

Comment: The "chrome from the driver" **is** your regular chrome browser. It launches with a different *profile* though. Are you saying you want to launch Chrome as if you had opened the browser, so it has your history, and is logged in with your Google account?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the replies ! 
Yes @GregBurghardt that is exactly what I want to achieve, I will try your method and will update my post accordingly, thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You need Chrome Driver because it implements WebDriver protocol and communicates with actual Chrome browser.
That way Chrome Driver and Chrome can be developed and maintained independently and Chrome browser code is not cluttered with/impacted by WebDriver protocol implementation.

From https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

```
WebDriver is an open source tool for automated testing of webapps across many browsers.
It provides capabilities for navigating to web pages, user input, JavaScript execution, and more.
ChromeDriver is a standalone server that implements the W3C WebDriver standard.
```